# How to compare 2 DateTime instances in C#?

Tags: datetime, compare

HELP!
Who knows how to compare DateTime objects. For example:

```
    Dictionary<DateTime, Person> _birthdays;
```

Then I add bunch of elements to the list, and want to find a person with the date 13. March 1995.

```
   if(_birthdays.Keys.Contains(new DateTime(13,3,1995))
```

blah blah ... And it always returns false ofcourse, because it is a whole new instance of DateTime and it probably has hours, seconds etc etc.... I want to compare YEAR MONTH DAY onlyyyy! Please help, it would make my code much simpler!

Comment: can you convert to strings (with your desired format) and just compare those strings?

Comment: Why do the keys in your dictionary have hours, seconds etc.? Should they? You should use `var person = _birthdays[someDateTime.Date];` if you know the person is in the dictionary. Otherwise use `TryGetValue` to see if the key is there. An issue: Why will there always be only one person with each birthday. Can't two persons be born on the same day?

Comment: yes, but I am not doing that project, it is something else, I just took that for an example XD but thanks so much anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` struct has a `Date` member, which gives you just the date.

```
var targetDate = new DateTime(13,3,1995);

if (_birthdays.Keys.Any(b => b.Date == targetDate))
....
```